# #AudioKit Can AudioKit and CoreAudio interwork in same iOS application?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiokit

I have a pre-existing iOS app written using Core Audio framework. There is a need to use MicroPhone and process Microphone input. `core-audio` does not support that. I am trying to use AudioKit just for Microphone. 
Program crashes with a simple statement like:

```
mic = AKMicrophone();
```

Is this interworking supported?

Comment: Core Audio does support microphone input.  Just use the Remote IO Audio Unit.